# asp.net automatically open lightbox with the paramaters

Tags: asp.net, lightbox

I have a page in c# that redirects to another page like

Response.Redirect("default.aspx?name=" + user.Firstname + "&surname=" + user.Lastname).

default.aspx has a lightbox. I want to open this lightbox when I redirect the page that include this lightbox. Also, I want to show the parameters in that lightbox input fields. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I tried something like "Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onload", someScript);" from the default.aspx.cs file. I wanted to get the parameters here and open the lightbox with these parameters. But I am a beginner for javascript and jquery, so I couldn't achieve.

Comment: i think you need to rephrase your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you cannot do it with Lightbox.
Lightbox plugin works on `<a>` tag and fetches value form href attribute. Also it specially design for Images as you can see if you provide a URL to page it doesnt load it.
For Intance,
if you provide,

```
<a href="page.html" id="a1" >Click Me</a>
```

it will keep showing the loading page.
Instead try using [thickbox](http://ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-thickbox.html) to show the current user parameters.
For thickbox to show a page you can use

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/thickbox.js"></script>
<a id="a1" href="#" title="Click me" class="thickbox">Call me</a>           

<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){           
        var anchor = document.getElementById("a1");
        var username= '<%= Request.QueryString["username"]%>';
        var url="second.html?height=500&width=700&modal=true&TB_iframe=true&username="+username;
        $('#a1').attr("href", url);
        anchor.click();                         
    });
</script>
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I found a link that uses a page opens like a lightbox. http://developlop.com/2012/03/asp-net-lightbox-ile-login-ekrani-yapimi/ It worked, but there can be better solutions. Thanks for your reply.